# How to pass a numpy.ndarray or keras metrix as a keras input

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, numpy-ndarray, tf.keras

I Have a list of matrix with shape(2,30000), I need to pass this info as an input of a deep learning model with tensorflow using a conv layer, but when I tried to pass this for training all the time I obtain

```
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

I have the list of the numpy array as a pandas series

```
0      [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
1      [[0.036600337822677166, 0.018300168911338583, ...
2      [[0.8671148170073495, 0.47065322955211747, 0.0...
3      [[0.024680190751413082, 0.007051483071832309, ...
4      [[0.0688791198957804, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0229597...
                             ...                        
549    [[0.024182541670333724, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0....
550    [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...

Name: tfidf, Length: 554, dtype: object
```

here is my model

```
def getmodel(num_words = 20000):
    x_input = keras.Input( shape=(2,30000),name="article1")  # Variable-length sequence of ints
    conv1d_1= layers.Conv1D(64, 2, input_shape=(2,30000), activation='relu')(x_input)
    global_1 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(conv1d_1)
    dense1 = layers.Dense(1024, name="dense1", activation="relu", )(global_1)
    encoder_conv_dense2 = layers.Dense(256, name="40_dense", activation="relu", )(dense1)
    encoder_conv_dense3 = layers.Dense(1, name="similar_result", activation="relu", )(encoder_conv_dense2)

    model = keras.Model(
        inputs=x_input,
        outputs=[encoder_conv_dense3],
    )
    keras.utils.plot_model(model, "my_paper_model.png", show_shapes=True)

    return model
```

and here how I tried to pass the info

```
def compile_model(model, optimizer, loss, loss_weight):
    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer,
        loss=loss,
        loss_weights=loss_weight,
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()]
    )
    return model

def train(df):
callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='accuracy', patience=40)
    callback2 = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=20)
    model = getmodel()
    model = compile_model(model, keras.optimizers.Adam(), keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), 0.05)
    history = model.fit(
        {"article1":df['tfidf']},
        {"similar_result": df['is_similar']},
        validation_split=0.3,
        epochs=400,
        batch_size=32,
        verbose=1,
        callbacks=[callback, callback2, ],
    )
```

I do not know how to pass my numpy matrix of 2 rows and 30,000 columns as input for keras and using it with conv layer.

Hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are providing as input is not in the correct format. in this case, of 3D input you need to provide an array of shapes (n_sample, timesteps, n_features). you can simply achieve this using `np.stack(df['tfidf'],0)`, which will result in an array of shape `(n_sample, 1, 30000)`.

I try to reproduce a dummy example below:

```
# create fake data
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['tfidf'] = [[np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)],
              [np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)],
              [np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)],
              [np.random.uniform(0,1, 30)]]
df['is_similar'] = np.random.randint(0,2, 4)
```

`df['tfidf']` is in this format:

```
0    [[0.09865182564241004, 0.5282608042987893, 0.5...
1    [[0.1361578046476558, 0.9866056058771036, 0.44...
2    [[0.38811373040427766, 0.5686225139326878, 0.8...
3    [[0.8254123154336716, 0.3542711784901068, 0.28...
Name: tfidf, dtype: object
```

Define the model and fit:

```
def getmodel():
    
    x_input = keras.Input(shape=(1,30),name="article1")  # Variable-length sequence of ints
    conv1d_1= layers.Conv1D(64, 1, activation='relu')(x_input)
    flat = layers.Flatten()(conv1d_1)
    dense1 = layers.Dense(1024, name="dense1", activation="relu")(flat)
    encoder_conv_dense2 = layers.Dense(256, name="40_dense", activation="relu")(dense1)
    encoder_conv_dense3 = layers.Dense(1, name="similar_result", activation="sigmoid")(encoder_conv_dense2)

    model = keras.Model(
        inputs=x_input,
        outputs=encoder_conv_dense3,
    )
    
    return model

model = getmodel()
model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy')
history = model.fit(
    {"article1": np.stack(df['tfidf'],0)},
    {"similar_result": df['is_similar']},
    epochs=3,
)
```